# synopse pdf changing paper size using Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF document using Synopse SynPDF library using Delphi. I need to be able to change the paper size on the fly to accommodate the document I am creating. The paper size's height needs to be changed anywhere from 11 inches to over 100 inches. I would also like to set the resolution of the image to be anywhere from 300 pixels per inch to 600 pixels per inch. This is what I have as a test.

```
   lPdf := TPdfDocumentGDI.Create;
   try
     lPdf.ScreenLogPixels:=600;

     lPdf.DefaultPageHeight := lPdf.ScreenLogPixels * 50;   // Since ScreenLogPixels holds the number of pixels per inch this should give me a 50 inch long page.
     lPdf.DefaultPageWidth := lPdf.ScreenLogPixels * 8;     // Same here with Page being 8 inches wide.
                                                                                // When viewing the document in Adobe Reader the page height and width 66.67 x 200.00 with nothing displayed
                                                                    // If I comment out the ScreenLogPixels line the page size becomes 10.67 x 66.67 with a pixel count of 768 x 4800 with the proper text on the document. 
     lPage := lPDF.AddPage;
     lPdf.VCLCanvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
     MyY:=300;
     lPDF.VCLCanvas.TextOut(100, 100, 'Width = ' + IntToStr(lPage.PageWidth) +
              ' Height = ' + IntToStr(lPage.PageHeight));
     for MyX := 1 to 400  do begin
        MyXLoc:=(MyX*120) mod (lPage.PageWidth);
        MyString:=IntToStr(MyX);
        lPDF.VCLCanvas.TextOut(MyXLoc, MyY, Mystring);
        lPDF.VCLCanvas.Font.Size:= lPDF.VCLCanvas.Font.Size+4;
        lPDF.VCLCanvas.Rectangle(MyXLoc, MyY, MyXLoc+lPDF.VCLCanvas.TextWidth(MyString), MyY+lPDF.VCLCanvas.TextHeight(MyString));
        MyY := MyY + lPDF.VCLCanvas.TextHeight(MyString);
     end;
     lPdf.SaveToFile('c:\Syntest.pdf');
  finally
     lPdf.Free;

  end;
```

Comment: How does what you have tried fail to meet expectations. Please don't say "it doesn't work".

Comment: With the line ScreenLogPixels := 600 nothing appears in the document and the document size is 66.67 in. x 200 in which means it is using 72 dpi resolution. If I comment out the line with 600 dpi the document is 10.67 x 66.67 in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PDF, all locations and sizes are stored in a logical value called a PDF unit. 1 PDF unit is equivalent to 1/72 of an inch.

`DefaultPageHeight` and `DefaultPageWidth` are values in PDF units, so 1/72th of a inch.

So for a 50' * 8' page, you can write:

```
 lPdf.DefaultPageHeight := 72 * 50; 
 lPdf.DefaultPageWidth := 72 * 8;
```

Then the VCL canvas available in `lPdf.VCLCanvas` will have a diverse coordinate system, depending in fact of `lPdf.ScreenLogPixels`.

So when you draw something in the `lPdf.VCLCanvas`, ensure you use the right size for coordinates, i.e. via `lPdf.VCLCanvasSize` values.

Comment: Arnaud, w.r.t. your recent blog post
http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/09/28/mORMot-show-case:-Illustrated-Spare-Parts-Catalogue

Plz, do not suggest statistics-based Google and Microsoft translator, just compare with specialized www.translate.ru and see

Comment: @Arioch'The I've put a link to translate.ru direct online translation.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez you may wish to edit your comment as your blogpost is at https://blog.synopse.info/?post/2015/09/28/mORMot-show-case%3A-Illustrated-Spare-Parts-Catalogue now, the previous link does not seem to work.